# Funny consequence of Hölder Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I really like this one:

> From Hölder, we get that the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$ always converges for $x \in \ell^p$ and $y \in \ell^q$. Since $\ell^p \subseteq \ell^q$ whenever $p < q$, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2$ also always converges.
> But this implies $\ell^p \subseteq \ell^2$ for any $p$.

Where is the problem?

Comment: " Since $\ell^p \subseteq \ell^q$ whenever $p < q$, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2$ also always converges."Can you explain why this assertion holds?

Comment: You can put $x$ as the sequence of $\ell^q$ in the first series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$, which converges.

Comment: So....$p < 2$ necessarily then?

Comment: $p \leq q$ with $1/p + 1/q = 1$ is the requirement.

Comment: @fwd yep, I just found this one funny and was trying to see if anyone would fall for it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything said is true, except for the last part; $\ell^p \subseteq \ell^2$ if, and only if $p \in (1,2)$. This is because, for the first series, $p$ and $q$ must be conjugates, and one conjugate is always in $(1,2)$ while the other is in $(2,\infty)$. To be able to say $\ell^p \subseteq \ell^q$, $p$ must be in the first interval.

Comment: A fun prank! :)